# How to insert a list into a map?

Tags: dart

I have 2 data one in an array and the other in a list. I need to send these data in API but combine them.

My first data look like this:

```
data1 = {vendorId: 17, vendorName: Dolphin Bakers};
```

and second is like this

```
data2 = [
  {id: 3, province: and, code: 56201},
  {id: 3, province: and, code: 56201},
];
```

I need to send it like this

```
{
  vendorId: 17,
  vendorName: Dolphin Bakers,
  data: [
    {id: 3, province: and, code: 56201},
    {id: 3, province: and, code: 56201},
  ],
}
```

I am trying to add second data in the first data

```
data1.add(data: data2);
```

Its showing error  `Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'add'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put a "data" key in the map:

```
data1["data"] = data2;
```